# is mount command a user space command or kernel command

Tags: mount, boot

as I understand, most of linux command are user space. but at boot time the system mount its root file system using `mount` command.

so is this command implemented within the kernel

Comment: `mount` is an executable binary, it calls the `mount` system call within the kernel. Check `man 1 mount` and `man 2 mount`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) is a command, i.e. a program, i.e. userspace code.

[`mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) is a system call, i.e. kernel code.

The `mount` command calls the `mount` system call to do the bulk of its job. In addition, it performs auxiliary tasks such as parsing its command line, consulting `/etc/fstab`, etc.